g++-13 the "-isystem" flag seems to work incorrectly with optimization enabled
File "include/header.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Eka
{
        int x;
public:
        Eka() { std::cout << x;};
        Eka(int y) : x(y) {}
        int Sqr() const { if(x > 5) return x + 1;};
};

file "eka.cpp"
#include <header.hpp>

int main() {
        Eka e;

        int x = e.Sqr();
        int y {};

        std::cin >> y;
        std::cout << x + y;

        return 0;
}

Build command:
g++ src.cpp -ores -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O1 -isystem include

Result:
g++11 hides warnings from "system" headers: compilation is successful
g++13.2 does not hide warnings: compilation failed.
With "-O0" everything works fine.
What's the problem ?
I expect the same behavior from different compiler versions regardless of whether the optimization flag is present.
I expect that warnings from the "system" headers will be suppressed when optimization is enabled and the "isystem" flag is used.

I haven't looked at the g++ source code, but I suspect that the problem is the system headers documentation is wrong.  It says "all warnings suppressed", but I think it ought to say "most warnings suppressed", and -Wuninitialized isn't one of the suppressed ones.  And, I guess, -O0 does not do the static analysis that would detect an uninitialized variable from a system header, whereas -O1 does.  Or perhaps inlining causes the header to trip the warning when inlined in main (which perhaps does not happen for -O0).

@Eljay, Maybe the documentation is not accurate (which would be surprising).
But then why is the behavior different from the previous gcc version?
In addition, if you replace "-isystem" with "-I", warnings will be generated even with
"-O0"

Maybe the documentation is not accurate (which would be surprising).  When the map (documentation) and the terrain (actual behavior) differ, trust the terrain.
